# What is the way to handle messages without os dependency in C++?

Tags: c++, ipc, message

Is there any way to write C++ programs to handle IPC that work in Linux and Windows?
Are there any C++ libraries doing it without dependency to operating system?

Comment: messages is pretty overloaded... Could you be more specific?

Comment: What kind of "messages" are we talking about here?

Comment: Nononoooo... Handel was a German Baroque composer. The word you're looking for is "handle".

Comment: he probably meant stuff beginning with `WM_`.

Comment: You could use cross-platform framework, like Qt, that would mostly abstract OS away and then you can only use framework's "messages" or similar mechanisms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "messages" you mean IPC (InterProcess Communication), then no, it's impossible without OS' involvement, and the way to do it will probably be different on every OS you can find in the universe. If by "messages" you mean any way of passing data inside your application, then yes, it can and should be done without OS' involvement.

In case of IPC, there is always [Boost.IPC](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) you can use, if you just have to pass messages. Of course, if you also need things like getting UI events etc., that will not be enough; [Qt](http://qt.digia.com/) is one of portable GUI toolkits commonly used in C++ (not that it's pretty, but it works).

Comment: Boost has IPC library. Uses OS facilities underneath, but sometimes you can close your eyes and pretend it isn't. :)

Comment: Yes, I do mean IPC. So, I need to write two instance of my program?

Comment: @JalalJaberi:  If your good, you only need to write two instances of the code that sends and receives the messages.  You could create a uniform API and your own libraries that implement the API for each OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about sockets (aka TCP/IP or UDP/IP), then you can use the sockets library and if you're careful you can have the same code work on both Windows and Unix variants. But the cross-platform sockets API has only very limited async ability (the `select` call and its associated scalability issues).

You could also use [libevent](http://libevent.org/). That is cross-platform and has much richer async semantics.

For things like named pipes or fifos... I know of no good cross-platform library for such things.